# Vue component template stops the script when a new line is added

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, atom-editor

I am creating a Vue template on the editor Atom.

The Vue Component template code works as long as I don't create a new line (Click Enter).

When I add a new line the previous lines get a red background in the editor, and the code stops working in the browser.

This is only true for Vue.Componenet -- Template section

Works:

```
Vue.component('tabs', {

template: '<div class="tabs is-centered"> Halp </div>',
```

Ruins everything:

```
Vue.component('tabs', {

template: '
<div class="tabs is-centered"> 
Halp 
</div>
',
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs add multiple lines to a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770972/vuejs-add-multiple-lines-to-a-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use backticks for a multiline string:

```
Vue.component('tabs', {

template: `
<div class="tabs is-centered"> 
Halp 
</div>
`,
```

Comment: Yikes, Was mixing up back ticks with single qoutes